# How to make the current coding structure more flexible

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I need help with my current workflow , though everthing works as expected but i would like to make the structure more robust.

I have a application where i change the data by string literal.

```
WAVEFRONT*TREEVIEW*Main$Text*GEOMETRY*TEXT SET TEXT ABCD
```

as shown in the image where "Main$Text" is the path of the data item the the tree structure.

[image]

1) First step-> i have a class to handle the command string and take appropriate action.

```
int SumCommandInterface::receiveCommand(std::string stdtsrCommand , const QModelIndex & RootIndex, TreeModel *myModel)
{   
    std::vector<std::string> vectorStrCommand;
    std::vector<std::string> vectorStrStarSplit;
    std::vector<std::string> vectorStrContainerNames;   
    boost::algorithm::trim(stdtsrCommand);
    boost::split(vectorStrCommand, stdtsrCommand, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);
    boost::split(vectorStrStarSplit, vectorStrCommand[0], boost::is_any_of("*"), boost::token_compress_on); 
    if (vectorStrStarSplit[1] == "TREEVIEW")  // for tree view
    {
        if (vectorStrCommand.size() < 4)
            return -1;

        boost::split(vectorStrContainerNames, vectorStrStarSplit[2], boost::is_any_of("$"), boost::token_compress_on);
        TreeItem* itm;
        QModelIndex  Index = RootIndex;
        for (auto &strName : vectorStrContainerNames)
        {
            if (!getTreeItem(strName, Index, myModel, &itm))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            Index = myModel->indexForTreeItem(itm);         
        }
        PluginTypeLookUp lookUp = lookUpPluginMap[vectorStrStarSplit[3]];
        Container *cont = itm->GetContainer();
        switch (lookUp)
        {
        case PluginTypeLookUp::GEOMTERY: // This can be function , texture etc, currently only showing code for geometry
        {
            Geometry *geom = cont->GetGeometry();
            if(vectorStrCommand[2] == "TEXT" )
                setFontPluginParam< Geometry , std::string >( geom, vectorStrCommand[2], vectorStrCommand[3]);

            if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "USESHADOW")
                setFontPluginParam< Geometry , bool >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], (vectorStrCommand[3] == "0" ? false : true) );

            if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "FONTSIZE" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "SHADOWDIRECTION")
                setFontPluginParam< Geometry, int >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], std::stoi(vectorStrCommand[3]) );

            if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "SHADOWDISTANCE" || vectorStrCommand[2] == "SHADOWOPACITY" || vectorStrCommand[2] == "KERNING" )
                setFontPluginParam< Geometry, float >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], std::stof(vectorStrCommand[3]));

        }
        break;
        case PluginTypeLookUp::TEXTURE:
        {
            Sum_Texture_2D *texture;
            texture = cont->GetTexturePointer();

            if(vectorStrCommand[2] == "TEXTUREPATH" )
                setTexturePluginParam< Sum_Texture_2D, std::string >(texture, vectorStrCommand[2], vectorStrCommand[3]);

            if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "POSITIONX" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "POSITIONY" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "POSITIONZ" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "SCALINGX" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "SCALINGY" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "SCALINGZ" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "ROTATIONX" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "ROTATIONY" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "ROTATIONZ ")
            {
                setTexturePluginParam< Sum_Texture_2D, float >(texture, vectorStrCommand[2], std::stof(vectorStrCommand[3]));
            }

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        return 1;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

i am passing the geometry parameter in command and based on that i have a if condition.

for example for USESHADOW the command would look like.

```
    WAVEFRONT*TREEVIEW*AMain$Text*GEOMETRY*TEXT SET USESHADOW 1
```

if Geometry parameter is TEXT the command would look like.

```
   WAVEFRONT*TREEVIEW*AMain$Text*GEOMETRY*TEXT SET TEXT ABC





        case PluginTypeLookUp::GEOMTERY: // This can be function , texture 
        etc, currently only showing code for geometry
            {
                Geometry *geom = cont->GetGeometry();
                if(vectorStrCommand[2] == "TEXT" )
                    setFontPluginParam< Geometry , std::string >( geom, vectorStrCommand[2], vectorStrCommand[3]);

                if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "USESHADOW")
                    setFontPluginParam< Geometry , bool >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], (vectorStrCommand[3] == "0" ? false : true) );

                if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "FONTSIZE" || vectorStrCommand[2] ==  "SHADOWDIRECTION")
                    setFontPluginParam< Geometry, int >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], std::stoi(vectorStrCommand[3]) );

                if (vectorStrCommand[2] == "SHADOWDISTANCE" || vectorStrCommand[2] == "SHADOWOPACITY" || vectorStrCommand[2] == "KERNING" )
                    setFontPluginParam< Geometry, float >(geom, vectorStrCommand[2], std::stof(vectorStrCommand[3]));

            }
            break;
```

The current issue i am facing is that if i have 30 different geometry parameters i would need to add 30 if conditions.

If i add more geometry types i would again need to revisit this code and add more parameters.

can i handle this step in more graceful way.

Comment: A `std::map` that maps the command strings to functions that take `string`, `string` and ultimately call the correct the correct `setFontPluginParam` could help out a lot. You wind up with code that looks like `commandmap[vectorStrCommand[2]](geom, vectorStrCommand[2], vectorStrCommand[3]);`

Comment: @user4581301 could you please show some dummy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic mapped look-up. These make great table-based menu systems and simple parsers. They may not be the fastest, but the code is really simple<sup>1</sup>, easy to read, and hard to screw up. Adding a new command or keyword can be as simple as adding another line to the `map`'s initializer.

All you need is:

1. A `std::map` to link the input text with the desired behaviour.
2. A bunch of functions all with the same prototype that execute the desired behaviours.  Lambda expressions are a great option when the behavour is simple since they keep all of the related code in one place

Here we go!

```
    #include <map>
    #include <functional>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    // standing in for setFontPluginParam
    template<class T>
    void template_func(const std::string& name, const T & data)
    {
        std::cout << name << ":" << data << std::endl;
    }

    // functions to convert the data to the correct type for template_func
    void text_func(const std::string & name, const std::string & text)
    {
        std::cout << "text_func "; // make output easier to interpret
        template_func(name, text); // call correct template specialization
    }

    void int_func(const std::string & name, const std::string & num)
    {
        std::cout << "int_func ";
        template_func(name, std::stoi(num));
    }

    // maps the name to the function. Note: If you're not messing around with lambdas or 
    // member functions, an old school function pointer may work better that std::function
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string &, const std::string &)>> call_function =
    {
     {"TEXT", text_func},
     {"INT", int_func},
     // same as above, but with a lambda expression to keep everything all in one place
     {"DOUBLE", [](const std::string & name, const std::string & num) {
         std::cout << "double_func ";
         template_func(name, std::stod(num));
      }}
    };

    void demo(const std::vector<std::string> & vectorStrCommand)
    {
        // uses map to look up correct function, then calls it
        // This is basically all that's left of the if/else if chain
        call_function[vectorStrCommand[2]](vectorStrCommand[2], vectorStrCommand[3]);
    }

    int main()
    {
        demo({"whatever", "whatever", "INT", "42"});
        demo({"whatever", "whatever", "TEXT", "I am the very model of a modern major general..."});
        demo({"whatever", "whatever", "DOUBLE", "3.14"});
    }
```

<sup>1</sup> Because it's simple it works best for simple things. Don't try to write a C++ compiler like this.

Comment: Just for curiosity what would be the fastest and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Depends on the number of items in the map and their type. `map` is great at cutting down the amount of searching in larger lists (ordered structures are easier to search) and `unordered_map` can be even faster with the right data (basically a hash table). But if the list is short, a simple array or going back to the if/else if chain can be faster because they are predictable. If the keys are all sequential numbers or characters, an array is hard to beat. For what you have here, strings, and with 30 different entries, probably `std::unordered_map` will be a good balance of fast and simple.